# Starting a thread in unmanaged c++ dll results in error after a while

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I had a hard time titling this question, sorry about that, let me try to explain.

Im aiming to create a c++ .dll which exposes functions for a C# WPF Application to hook on to, alongside a callback. Right now Im testing this, but Im stuck at trying to run a thread indefinetly until a condition is met and it stops (In this case a simple while(run) where the boolean run is set from the C# application).

I get it to start and update a simple label in my C# WPF application, but after a while (Varying amount of time) it throws the error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module.
```

A bit of googling suggests that this has to do with C#s garbage collection and it killing the thread started in C#?

C++Code goes as follows:

```
#include "pch.h"

typedef void(__stdcall* PFN_MYCALLBACK)(int number);

PFN_MYCALLBACK test;
int cnt = 0;
bool run = false;



extern "C" {
    static void tester()
    {
        while (run)
        {
            Sleep(100);
            test(cnt++);
        }
        test(-1);
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) BSTR DisplayHelloFromDLL()
    {
        return SysAllocString(L"Hello World");
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void init(PFN_MYCALLBACK callback)
    {
        test = callback;
        run = true;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) bool isrunning() 
    {
        return run;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void start()
    {
        std::thread(tester).detach();
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) void stop() 
    {
        run = false;
    }
}
```

C# Code goes as follows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("ebAvayaRTD", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
        static extern string DisplayHelloFromDLL();


        public delegate void MyCallback(int i);
        [DllImport("ebAvayaRTD")]
        public static extern void init(MyCallback callback);

        [DllImport("ebAvayaRTD")]
        public static extern void start();

        [DllImport("ebAvayaRTD")]
        public static extern void stop();

        [DllImport("ebAvayaRTD")]
        public static extern bool isrunning();

        public static MainWindow instance { get; private set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            instance = this;

            init(test);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                start();
            });
        }

        public static void test(int i) {
            instance.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                instance.lblout.Content = i;
            });
        }
    }
```

In this version the callback is a static function, Ive tested it as a normal non-static one as well, but with the same result. What am I missing here?

The goal is to have the DLL be a interface to a API which is alive until a disconnection request happens.

I have to admit that Im not sure what fails. If its the thread running the loop or if somehow the callback function is no longer accessible.

Comment: I also tested using thread.join() in the start function of the C++ portion of this, but no difference other than it counted further before crashing

Comment: ExecutionEngineException occurs when the garbage collector detects that the GC heap is corrupted.  Strongly associated with unmanaged code, a buffer overflow while writing into a managed object is typical.  No great candidates here, but `init(test);` is certainly wrong.  That creates a MyCallback delegate object that is not referenced anywhere after init() returns.  So the GC will eventually destroy it, now the unmanaged callback will fail.  This normally generates a diagnostic from the CallbackOnCollectedDelegate MDA.  Fix by storing it in a static variable or using GCHandle.Alloc().

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. What would be best practice in this situation? And how would I implement it? I cant seem to find any good explanation as to how I would do it.

Comment: Scratch that, doing multiple things at the same time rarely is a good idea. Solved it by storing in static variable. Thank you!